# Why does JVM error occur?

Tags: java, javafx

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007ff17a60c678, pid=4219, tid=140673779791616
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0-b124) (build 1.8.0-ea-b124)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.0-b66 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x665678]  jni_invoke_nonstatic(JNIEnv_*, JavaValue*, _jobject*, JNICallType, _jmethodID*, JNI_ArgumentPusher*, Thread*)+0x38
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /media/data/K's World/javaFX/ChatApp/hs_err_pid4219.log
Compiled method (c1)   16675  988       3       java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean::set (14 bytes)
 total in heap  [0x00007ff16535ef50,0x00007ff16535f2a0] = 848
 relocation     [0x00007ff16535f070,0x00007ff16535f0a0] = 48
 main code      [0x00007ff16535f0a0,0x00007ff16535f1c0] = 288
 stub code      [0x00007ff16535f1c0,0x00007ff16535f250] = 144
 metadata       [0x00007ff16535f250,0x00007ff16535f258] = 8
 scopes data    [0x00007ff16535f258,0x00007ff16535f268] = 16
 scopes pcs     [0x00007ff16535f268,0x00007ff16535f298] = 48
 dependencies   [0x00007ff16535f298,0x00007ff16535f2a0] = 8
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

I am writing chat App in javaFx..and I am using eclipse IDE..
My Application is running well but I don't know why suddenly application has been stopped.

Comment: `Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again`....That's why it has suddenly stopped

Comment: where do I apply this command?...I am using eclipse IDE

Comment: Q: What platform are you running Eclipse on?  Linux?  Which distro and version?  Q: Is your app 100% Java, or are you making JNI calls?

Comment: If you're on Linux (any Linux), you can 1) Start a terminal session (command line), 2) Type `ulimit -c unlimited`, 3) Start Eclipse (from the same command line session).  But again, please 1) specify your platform, 2) tell us whether or not you're using JNI

Comment: still JVM error occurs..May I write error here?

Comment: See my post below.  It sounds like you've encountered a known Java 8 bug; I don't know if there's a fix available yet - your "safest bet" is probably to downgrade your default Java.  You'll also need to modify your Eclipse project to use the new JRE.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're running JavaFX with Java 8 on Linux, and you've run into this bug:

> https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8141687
>
> App crashes while starting Main.class in JavaFx
>
> ava version "1.8.0_60" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.8.0_60-b27) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
>
> ADDITIONAL OS VERSION INFORMATION : Mint17.2 Cinnamon 64Bit

SUGGESTION: Try a different version of Java/JavaFX.

1. Run `sudo update-alternatives --config java` to see what alternatives are already present on your system.  I would downgrade to Java 1.7 if possible.

   - https://askubuntu.com/questions/272187/setting-jdk-7-as-default
2. If there are no suitable candidates, use `apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`:

   - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (except that it was java-8-oracle build 101) and found out why it was happening:

I have a login screen that appears before my main application and that screen gets closed after the login occurs and, apparently, closing it (or even hiding it) and showing a new window makes it crash.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14838901)

Comment: "My Application is running well but I don't know why suddenly application has been stopped."


I gave him a possible cause of why the crash might be happening, is that not good enough? Since it's a JVM error it's difficult to pinpoint exactly why it is happening.

Comment: AfterWind: Thanks for the tip. I had the same problem after change the workflow to: stageMain.show(); stageLogin.close();. The crash never occurs