# SIGSEGV - Fatal Error in JavaFX Application - libjvm.so

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, java-8, jvm, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to run a javaFX application on Intellij Idea. The application worked fine with windows but I've been getting this crash ever since i moved to Linux.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f91c4dd98f8, pid=11903, tid=0x00007f9179b89700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x6d28f8]  jni_invoke_nonstatic(JNIEnv_*, JavaValue*, _jobject*, JNICallType, _jmethodID*, JNI_ArgumentPusher*, Thread*)+0x38
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /home/manish/core or core.11903
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/manish/hs_err_pid11903.log
Compiled method (c1)    5269 1395       3       java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean::set (14 bytes)
 total in heap  [0x00007f91b05f3250,0x00007f91b05f35c0] = 880
 relocation     [0x00007f91b05f3378,0x00007f91b05f33a8] = 48
 main code      [0x00007f91b05f33c0,0x00007f91b05f34e0] = 288
 stub code      [0x00007f91b05f34e0,0x00007f91b05f3570] = 144
 metadata       [0x00007f91b05f3570,0x00007f91b05f3578] = 8
 scopes data    [0x00007f91b05f3578,0x00007f91b05f3588] = 16
 scopes pcs     [0x00007f91b05f3588,0x00007f91b05f35b8] = 48
 dependencies   [0x00007f91b05f35b8,0x00007f91b05f35c0] = 8
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Full Log Here: https://pastebin.com/6xRkkNt0

**Edit**
This was caused by stage.close() for login screen coming before the loading of another stage in JavaFX. Switched the order of the code and its fixed now.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/35263553/104891.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Helped!